# How can I create a redirect for Apache 2.2 webserver on Windows-7

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, redirect

I'd like to have a redirection web page from one page to another so that I can have two names for the same web page on my server. I tried creating a windows shortcut, but that did not work. Please suggest how to have one page be a pointer to another.

So the following two would be the same without duplicating a page's definition, but instead by linking:

```
http://www.domain.com/something/index.html
http://www.domain.com/index.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://superuser.com/questions/102793/how-can-i-create-a-redirect-for-apache-2-2-webserver-on-windows-7/102794#102794

Comment: I believe I just provided WilliamKF with a link to my answer that I posted on superuser.com

Comment: @"Petrik" - not visiting my link and seeing it was an answer before commenting is not at all useful

Comment: @"Petrik" - I see, I should have said "I have an answer for you, but you need to post at Server Fault first!"